# Why are the files downloaded by my app deleted after uninstalling it?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

My application downloads files from Google Drive by the DownloadManager to the public Download directory. Everything works perfectly, except that when I uninstall my app, the downloded files are automatically deleted. Why?

- my two test phones: 1 under Nougat and 1 under marshmallow

Is there something I did not follow and understood with Marshmallow and Nougat?

Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: where exactly do you download files to? I think that you download them to your app's files directory, which is removed when your app is uninstalled.

Comment: In public Download directory as mentionned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a real regression !! I had not noticed it yet.

Solutions if you want your downloaded files to persist after uninstalling your app are:

- 1 not to use DownloadManager :))
- 2 rename your files after Download process
- 3 move your files away

Source:https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/02/09/changes-downloadmanager-behavior.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Android 6.0 not only removes your entries from the Downloads app, but also removes the downloaded files. This is true even if you specifically downloaded to a location that should survive an uninstall, such as via `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`